# Changing the template of a Joomla Site. What we should know

Tags: discussion

This question has not been covered so far in JSE, and I think it is one of the essential questions of beginners in Joomla. The concept of the templates and the modules positions can be confusing, so let's try to create a simple guide with answers that will cover the essentials of the topic and will be a good reference in the site.

How do you install and configure a new template on a Joomla website? What are the steps involved and things users should know or avoid, in order to change their template successfully?

Comment: This is not a question. If you have a question please ask it. The best answers are given when the question is short, to the point and focussed. Question marks (?) are a big help…

Comment: He is basically asking "How to install and configure a Joomla template" He many not "need" it but is asking it for the benefit of whoever might need it. True an edit should be done but this is a great question.

Comment: @Seth: Well, I am just trying to enrich the website with content, that many users might search for in the web, and serving the community as a whole, while giving more visibility to this site. You are free to improve the question.

Comment: I've flagged to migrate this to the meta site as it's still a good point. A proper question should be asked which I assume will then turn into a community wiki

Comment: @FFewin please repost this is a clear and simple form on JSE. Make the question as clear as possible so that the answers can also be simple.